# How to estimate conditional volatilities using E-GARCH, at high speed, in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to estimate conditional volatility in R using E-GARCH model. I am using rugarch package as it is very efficient in terms of speed until now in R.

I need to run E-GARCH on monthly stock returns on each stock. For each stock I have about 522 months data and there are 26000 stocks.

I am estimating E-GARCH on an expanding window basis, where the minimum window is 100 monthly returns data on each stock. In other words I need to estimate E-GARCH for about 12,792,000 times. The estimation seems right but, it is taking too long to run these estimations in total.

I was able to run for 1000 stocks in a single day. But, I stopped because at this speed I will be able to finish all the estimations in 26 days. Is there a way to estimate this more efficiently in terms of speed and time?

The code I am using is just ugarchroll with lapply. The data format is given below where first three columns represent external regressors in the mean model and 1,2,....,6 represent stocks. In complete data I have more than 26000 columns.

```
date        Mkt.RF  SMB      HML    RF      1   2   3   4   5       6
19630731    -0.39   -0.55   -0.82   0.27    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA    -0.045161
19630830    5.07    -0.97   1.63    0.25    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA     0.121081
19630930    -1.57   -0.32   0.19    0.27    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA    -0.07767
19631031    2.53    -0.54   -0.11   0.29    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA     0.057895
19631129    -0.85   -1.1    1.66    0.27    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA     0.246766
19631231    1.83    -1.96   -0.11   0.29    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA    -0.004016


spec<-ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "eGARCH", garchOrder = c(3, 3),
              submodel = NULL, external.regressors = NULL, variance.targeting = T),
              mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0), include.mean = T, archex = FALSE,
                                external.regressors = as.matrix(ts[,1:3])))

CVOL<-ugarchroll(spec, data = subset(ts1,complete.cases(ts1)), n.ahead = 1, 
                       n.start = 100, refit.every = 1, refit.window =       "recursive", 
                       solver = "hybrid", fit.control = list(),
                       calculate.VaR = TRUE, VaR.alpha = c(0.01, 0.025, 0.05),
                       keep.coef = TRUE)@forecast$densit[2]
```

I am using computer with 16 GB of RAM, Core i-7 processor.
Q. Is there a way to estimate this more efficiently in terms of speed and time? Thank you.

Comment: Unless you design a less computationally intensive model, this won't get much faster. The rugarch package is written in C++ and is efficient.

Comment: Does it help if I shift to any other software like stata, eviews or others?